# The mashup resources page reader is not available- Error

Tags: excel, powerquery

The mashup resources page reader is not available- Error

I recently started getting this error after about a month of running a macro which ran perfectly for a month with no errors. The macro updates pivots, power queries, and charts. When the error comes up, I am able to just click close and the macro continues and everything updates correctly. After researching online, it looks like the error may be caused by a row in the power query editor that is different from when the pivots and charts were first created. However, I can't figure out where this issue is occurring or what the difference is. It is also difficult because all the data appears to be updating correctly. Is there anyway to figure this out?